# Can I sync only one Core Data Entity to CloudKit if it has relationship to another Entitiy

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

In my app I have 2 Core Data Entities: Categories and Items. They have One-to-Many relationship.
I need to backup Items to the user's private CloudKit DB, but not the Categories. I will do it via 2 different local Configurations.

My question: is it possible to save one and not the other and keep the relationship locally (as the relationship will be optional in CloudKit)?  What will happen when the user gets a new device, opens my app with Categories, and download their Items from CloudKit - will they "connect" with the local Categories?

Comment: I very much doubt that this will work but why only backup one entity? Will Categories never change?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, Categories are downloaded from the Cloud. And the Source of Truth for them is the Cloud. I think downloading them from the Cloud to store them in CloudKit is an even worse idea.

Comment: You probably need to store some identifier for Category in Item so you can match them in code. I am not sure if you should even have a relationship between them in Core Data